# Extracting subset of multiple GeoTIFFs

Tags: python, gdal

I have a set of DEMs that are 1x1 degree tiles (GeoTIFFs). I want to run some analysis on portions of these files that could potentially span up to 4 tiles at a time or a portion of up to 4 at a time as seen in the red area of the attached image.

I can load all four tiles into a multi-dimensional array then determine which tile I need to be in when looking for a specific point and extract that data, but thought it would be faster to first extract only the points I need into a single array making my analysis much faster.

I'm using Python right now and the gdal lib, but loading this much data into memory is slow. I could probably build an array of points, but then would have to determine how to reference that array based on the lat/lon values I'm looking for.

Here is some code:

```
#determine minimum bounding rectangle of area of interest and get the max and min lat and lon vals to determine how many tiles my area will span

maxlat = 0
minlat = 0
maxlon = 0
minlon = 0
maxrad = 0

llpairs = [(stlat,stlon),(endlat,endlon)]

llcnt = 0

for ll in llpairs:

        if llcnt == 0:

                minlat = ll[0]
                maxlat = ll[0]
                minlon = ll[1]
                maxlon = ll[1]
        else:
                if ll[0] < minlat:
                        minlat = ll[0]
                if ll[0] > maxlat:
                        maxlat = ll[0]
                if ll[1] < minlon:
                        minlon = ll[1]
                if ll[1] > maxlon:
                        maxlon = ll[1]
        llcnt+=1

max_file_lat = math.floor(maxlat)+1

min_file_lat = math.floor(minlat)+1

n_vert_quads = (max_file_lat - min_file_lat) + 1

print("max_file_lat: ",max_file_lat)
print("min_file_lat: ",min_file_lat)
print("# vert quads: ",n_vert_quads)

ew_str = 'W'
ns_str = 'N'
#if west hemisphere
if maxlon < 0:
        max_file_lon = math.floor(maxlon)
else:
        max_file_lon = math.floor(maxlon)+1

if minlon < 0:
        min_file_lon = math.floor(minlon)
else:
        min_file_lon = math.floor(minlon)+1


n_horiz_quads = (max_file_lon - min_file_lon) +1

max_file_lon = abs(max_file_lon)
min_file_lon = abs(min_file_lon)

print("max_file_lon: ",max_file_lon)
print("min_file_lon: ",min_file_lon)
print("# horiz quads: ",n_horiz_quads)

lon_str = ''
lon_filenum = 0
lat_str = ''
lastlon = 0
lastlat = 0
file_str = ''

t_array = []

#now determine which tiles (filenames) I need to work with

for x in range(1,n_horiz_quads + 1):

        #if both lons are neg, then we are in western hemisphere

        if(minlon < 0 and maxlon <0):
                ew_str = 'W'
        if(minlon > 0 and maxlon >0):
                ew_str = 'E'

        if x==1:
                if(minlon < 0):
                        ew_str = 'W'
                        lastlon = -1
                if(minlon > 0):
                        ew_str = 'E'
                        lastlon = 1
                lon_str = "%03d" % min_file_lon
        else:

                if min_file_lon > max_file_lon: #we are in western
                        lon_str = "%03d" % (min_file_lon - x +1)
                        lastlon = -1
                if min_file_lon < max_file_lon:
                        lon_str = "%03d" % (min_file_lon + x -1)
                        lastlon = 1
                if(minlon < 0 and maxlon >0): #at some point we will cross 0
                        ew_str = 'E'
                        if(lastlon == -1):
                                if (min_file_lon - x +1) == 0: #we are at the prime meridian
                                        lon_str = '000'
                                        lastlon = 1
                                else:
                                        lon_str = "%03d" % (min_file_lon - x +1)
                        else:
                                lon_str = "%03d" % (-min_file_lon + x)
                                lastlon = 1


        for y in range(1,n_vert_quads + 1):

                print("y ",y)
                if (minlat > 0 and maxlat >0):
                        ns_str = 'N'
                if (minlat < 0 and maxlat < 0):
                        ns_str = 'S'
                if y == 1:
                        if minlat > 0: #all north
                                ns_str = 'N'
                                lastlat = 1
                        if minlat < 0: #all south
                                ns_str = 'S'
                                lastlat = -1
                        lat_str = str(abs(min_file_lat))
                else:
                        if min_file_lat > max_file_lat: # in southern hemi
                                lat_str = str(min_file_lat - y + 1)
                                lastlat = -1
                        if min_file_lat < max_file_lat: #in north hemi
                                lat_str = str(min_file_lat + y -1)
                        if (minlat < 0 and maxlat > 0):
                                if (lastlat == -1):
                                        if(min_file_lat -x + 1) == 0:
                                                lat_str = '00'
                                                lastlat = 1
                                        else:
                                                lat_str = str(min_file_lat - y + 1)
                                else:
                                        lat_str = str(-min_file_lat + y)
                                        lastlat = 1
                file_str = ns_str + lat_str + ew_str + lon_str
                tfile_str = file_str + ".tif"
                print ("file: " + file_str)
                tds = add_file(tfile_str,'terrain')
                t_array.append((tds,float(lat_str),float(lon_str)))

#now get values along a line within the bounded region with start 
stlat/stlon and end endlat/endlon

(ptArray,pathProf) = get_path_values(stlat,stlon,endlat,endlon)

def get_path_values(stlat,stlon,endlat,endlon):
        global t_array
        global c_array
        bearing = get_bearing(stlat,stlon,endlat,endlon)

        print ("start: " + str(stlat) + ", " + str(stlon) + " end: " + str(endlat) + ", " + str(endlon))
        print ("bearing: " + str(bearing))

        stpt = geopy.Point(stlat,stlon)
        endpt = geopy.Point(endlat,endlon)

        dist = geopy.distance.great_circle(stpt,endpt).km

        print ("dist(km): " + str(dist))

        numpts = dist*1000/10
        npts = math.floor(numpts)
        npts = npts -2
        print ("npts ", npts)
        ptdist = 0.01 #km
        points = []
        profile = []
        ptds = 0
        current_ds_lat = 0
        current_ds_lon = 0
        #determine which dataset we need

        destlatm = math.modf(stlat)
        destlonm = math.modf(stlon)
        destlatint = destlatm[1]
        destlonint = destlonm[1]

        ptds = get_dataset(stlat,stlon)
        print('start ptds ',ptds)
        dataset = t_array[ptds][0]
        band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

        cols = dataset.RasterXSize
        rows = dataset.RasterYSize

        transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

        print("cols " + str(cols) + ", rows " + str(rows));
       
        xOrigin = transform[0]
        yOrigin = transform[3]
        pixelWidth = transform[1]
        pixelHeight = -transform[5]

        data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)

        stcol = int((stlon - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
        strow = int((yOrigin - stlat ) / pixelHeight)
        stelev = data[strow][stcol]
        points.append((stlon,stlat,stelev,stclt))
        profile.append({"elevation":stelev,"clutter":stclt,"dist":0})

        newpt =  stpt
        oldlat = destlatm
        oldlon = destlonm
        ptds = 0
        for n in range(1,npts):
                #print("point ",n)
                dest = geopy.distance.distance(kilometers=ptdist).destination(newpt, bearing)
                destlat = dest.latitude
                destlatm = math.modf(destlat)
                destlon = dest.longitude
                destlonm = math.modf(destlon)
                destlatint = destlatm[1]
                destlonint = destlonm[1]

                newpt = dest
                #find the file for this point
                if (destlatint != oldlat or destlonint != oldlon):
                        print('getting dataset for this point')
                        ptds = get_dataset(destlat,destlon)
                        print("ptds is ",ptds)
                        oldlat = destlatint
                        oldlon = destlonint
                
                        dataset = t_array[ptds][0]

                        band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

                        cols = dataset.RasterXSize
                        rows = dataset.RasterYSize

                        transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

                        print("cols " + str(cols) + ", rows " + str(rows));
                        
                        xOrigin = transform[0]
                        yOrigin = transform[3]
                        pixelWidth = transform[1]
                        pixelHeight = -transform[5]

                        data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)

                dcol = int((destlon - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
                drow = int((yOrigin - destlat ) / pixelHeight)

                elev = data[drow][dcol]


                print("pt ", destlat,destlon)

                #find the file we need to pass
                print('elevation ', elev)
                points.append((destlon,destlat,elev))
                profile.append({"elevation":elev,"clutter":clt,"dist":0.01*n})


        #now get the end pt

        destlat = endlat
        destlon = endlon
        destlatm = math.modf(destlat)
        destlonm = math.modf(destlon)
        destlatint = destlatm[1]
        destlonint = destlonm[1]

        if (destlatint != oldlat or destlonint != oldlon):
                print('getting dataset for this point')
                ptds = get_dataset(destlat,destlon)
                print("ptds is ",ptds)
                dataset = t_array[ptds][0]

                band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

                cols = dataset.RasterXSize
                rows = dataset.RasterYSize


                transform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()


                xOrigin = transform[0]
                yOrigin = transform[3]

                pixelWidth = transform[1]
                pixelHeight = -transform[5]

                data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, cols, rows)
               
        dcol = int((destlon - xOrigin) / pixelWidth)
        drow = int((yOrigin - destlat ) / pixelHeight)
        elev = data[drow][dcol]

        points.append((destlon,destlat,elev))
        profile.append({"elevation":elev,"dist":dist})
        return (points,profile)

        
def get_dataset(lat,lon):

        acnt = 0
        apos = -1
        global t_array
        #determine which dataset we need
        for ds in t_array:
                alat = ds[1]
                alon = ds[2]
                print("alat alon ",alat, alon," lat lon ",lat,lon)
                if (lat <= alat and lat > (alat - 1) and abs(lon) <= alon and abs(lon) < (alon +1)):
                        apos = acnt
                        print("data set position " +  str(apos))
                acnt+=1
        return apos
```

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Extracting elevation values repetitively and somewhat randomly within that red area.

Comment: A simple way to solve at least part of the problem is to combine the source images into a virtual raster dataset https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html with gdalbuildvrt https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html.

Comment: That is interesting, but while this is a simple example, I could be dealing with positions anywhere in the world. I may need to load 1 tile or 4 for any given set of points. It needs to be done in real time with any two sets of start and end coordinates. It works as is, but takes about 5 seconds every time I have to load a new tile into memory when I cross a boundary.

Comment: Some kind of image index approach is the common way to do it. GeoServer calls is image mosaic https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html, MapServer as tileindex, GDAL VRT is one sort of index, and there are others.

Comment: I've basically created an indexed array of the file objects loaded into memory. The long part comes when I actually load the band from that tile to get the data points. I'm not sure why it takes several seconds to load the band, when gdal CLI can find a point in less than 1 sec. It seems like the python gdal lib is doing something different. Once the band is read, the lookups are fast, but switching between bands when crossing a border is painful.